# Show month date using @Html.DisplayFor()

Tags: c#

Would line to  know if there is some way to show a month, day and year using the   @Html.DisplayFor(). I have a date such as 3/10/2013 but need to show each month day and year separate on a printable form.

Comment: `DisplayFor(x => x.SomeDate.Month)`?

Comment: do you want to display the date like <span>year</span> <span>month</span> <span>day</span>

Answer (score 1):

In your view model mark date field the with following attibute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM dddd yyyy}")]
DateTime MyDateField
```

You may set any desirable date format